# Who are the genetically enhanced friends Sloan is referring to?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In the episode [Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Inter_Arma_Enim_Silent_Leges_(episode)), Sloan [says](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/565.htm) the following:

> BASHIR: I'm incapable of making a diagnosis by simply looking at a
> man.
>
> SLOAN: Your **genetically enhanced** friends determined that Gul
> Damar killed a woman just by watching him give a political speech. I'm
> sure you can do better than that.

Who are the "genetically enhanced friends" Sloan is talking about? Are they the people Bashir meets in [Statistical Probabilities](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Statistical_Probabilities_(episode))?

Does this mean they were working for S31 or was Sloan manipulating them like he did Bashir?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, he's referring to Jack, Lauren, Patrick and Sarina, who during the course of the episode *Statistical Probabilities* determined that Gul Damar had murdered someone close to him.

> JACK: Methought I heard a voice cry, Sleep no more! Damar does murder sleep!
>
> PATRICK: He's killed someone.
>
> LAUREN: Someone close to him.
>
> <sub>ST:DS9 - *Statistical Probabilities*</sub>

There does not seem to be any implication that they were working directly for Sloan or Section 31, he was simply referencing the events of the earlier episode.